# When will the API allow posting of questions and answers?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, write-access

I am planning on building a client for the Stack Exchange Sites, but it seems you cannot post any information via the API yet.

Is this going to happen at any time soon? It seems a pain to force users to move to the web version, especially if they are on a mobile device.

Answer (score 1):

Just for posterity:
Version 2.1 (released 2012-09-04) supported [posting comments](http://api.stackexchange.com/docs/create-comment).
Version 2.2 (released 2014-02-10) supports posting [questions](http://api.stackexchange.com/docs/create-question), [answers](http://api.stackexchange.com/docs/create-answer), and comments.

[More reading material on write access here.](http://api.stackexchange.com/docs/write)